Colabのポップアップウィンドウが小さく表示されてしまって中身を見ることができません
Colabのポップアップウィンドウが小さく表示されてしまって中身を見ることができません。
こちらの方と同じ内容の問題と思われますが解消方法がわかりません。
Google Colaboratory 使用時にポップアップウィンドウが小さく内容が読めないケースが発生する
使用環境はWindows11,Google Chromeです。
どなたか改善方法をご教授くださいますようお願いいたします。

追記
画像の現象はランタイム＞ランタイムのタイプを変更　のところで発生しましたが、他にもポップアップウィンドウが出てくる場面では同じ状態でした。
EdgeやノートPC（Google Chrome)では同じ現象は現れませんでした。
ですができればやはりデスクトップの方のGoogle Chromeでも使えるようにしたいのです。
もしかしたらChromeの拡張機能が影響しているのかもしれませんが、どれなのかわかりません...

この辺のヘルプ記事を参考に調べてみてはどうでしょう？ Windows で画面の解像度を変更する の画面に表示されるもののサイズを変更する, Google Chrome ヘルプのテキスト、画像、動画のサイズを変更する（拡大、縮小）, 他にはGoogle Colaboratory画面右上の歯車アイコンをクリックして表示される設定ダイアログのエディタの項目、あるいは左上に並んだメニューの「ヘルプ」の「よくある質問」の中を探すとか？

ご教授ありがとうございました。
やってみましたが変化はありませんでした...

そう言えば何をしようとしてどのような操作をすると問題のものが表示されるのでしょう？ それが質問に記述されていれば知らない人でも再現させて確かめられるのでは？ そして参照した質問や私のコメントで紹介したことのうち、何をどうやったのかを詳細に追記してみてください。あと表示された内容を知るだけならF12キー押下や該当ダイアログをマウス右クリックの「検証」で開発者ツールを起動すればHTMLの内容を読めると思うのですが。あるいはEdgeブラウザに変えてやってみるとか。質問の改善についてはこちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？

シークレットモードで開くとどうなりますか？ 崩れますか崩れませんか

この記事を参考に拡張機能が原因かどうか確かめてみるとか？ 拡張機能を一時的に全部OFFにしてChromeを起動する方法 それで直るようなら拡張機能を1個づつ調べてみるしか無いでしょう。Copilotで質問したら、他にはブラウザのキャッシュをクリアしてみるとか、Google colaboratoryの設定をリセットしてみるとか答えがありましたが、リセットする方法は見つからなかったので仕様が変わったのかもしれません。

その方法でチェックしてみたら、セキュリティソフトの拡張機能が影響しているようでした。外しても問題ないものだったので外して解決することができました。ありがとうございました！！

解決したようであればコメント欄で終わらせず、個別の回答として投稿してみてください。

一応書いておくと ...
シークレットモードでは, (通常は)拡張機能を使用できません。
なのでたぶん普通に(崩れずに)見えたはずで, すなわち, 「原因が拡張機能かどうか」を判断する材料にできたかもしれません。/ 個別の回答として投稿する場合, その検証も含めて書くのも良いかもしれません
